# Custom button disabled by default?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, jquery, html

I'm overriding one template, in order to allow multiple payments, so it have to have a button to call an aditional form, the thing is the button is already disable when the template is loaded.

The template is:

`default\template\checkout\onepage\payment.phtml`,

the HTML code of the button is this:

`<input type="button" value="Registrar" name="ekl-btn-registrar" id="ekl-btn-registrar" class="button" disabled="" autocomplete="off">`

Notice that the `disabled` attribute is empty (is not equal to `enabled`). I've trying to enabled it or just drop the attribute by using jQuery, with no success. Anyway, IMHO the simpliest solution is find out where the disabling is happening and "disable the disabling", the question is: where?

Answer (score 0):

A jquery solution is not the best way, but here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/TFTvn/1/

I also doubt that disabled="" is legit,  is..